# How to create a randomly generated line using Swift in xCode

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

[image: Example_1]
[image: Example_2]

In the Image above (Top Image), suppose the black boundary is the phone.

What i was trying to achieve is to randomly generate the red path from the top of the screen and at the same time the red line (path) moves downwards.

Notice how the red path is random and does not have a uniform shape.

My question is how do i achieve this?

I know this has something to do with the random function.

But then generating the random path has been my main obstacle since 8 hours.

I could not generate a shape at every interval of the timer with a specific x coordinate and y coordinate but then as you can see in the next image, how would i generate the line at an angle (rotated)

Have tried hard to search everywhere on the internet but failed.

I always keep stackoverflow my last destination after I fail to achieve any functionality after numerous hours.

Would really appreciate if anyone could help me out with this.

Comment: Please include some of your attempted code

Comment: For a random number use: `arc4random_uniform()`. [man arc4random](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html)

Comment: I just used a UIView with a width of 12 and height of x (size of phone screen) and then i could just move it downwards by using `myView.frame.origin.y -= 5`

Comment: @Zaph - But here in this situation where do i use the random number ?

Comment: the problem with a random number is you are likely to to see more of a waveform that a line, which will not produce a good result. You should def have some form of bounding algorithm to ensure your line looks more like your example.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you could achieve the effect you wish by starting at the top center, and repeatedly choosing 2 random numbers: how far down to go, and how far horizontally to go (positive or negative), until you got to the bottom of the screen.  You'd have to be careful not to go off either edge, or you could instead choose a random x-coordinate each step.

Comment: I have tried this by using a random function and using that random number to the x coordinate and y coordinate but to what do i apply these change of coordinates ? As you said, The UIView will start from the top center and then as it comes down, then what do i do when its length crosses the top edge of the screen ? and also how do i apply an angle ?

Comment: Don't allow movements up, only down; I don't understand what "apply an angle" means.

Comment: Sweet Answer, I'm creating an app as well, and wanted to move a sprite along a random path. Your answer has planted some creative fireworks in my brain :) Thanks